# PHP - display directories using set of names from text file

Tags: php, text, foreach, directory, glob

There are more than 5 folders in the 'central' folder but I want to display only these 3 folders listed in this text file.

foldername.txt:

- folder1
- folder2
- folder3

Get the names:

```
$read = fopen('foldername.txt', 'r');
$getname = file_get_contents('foldername.txt');

fclose($read);
```

Now I want to display each foldername from the textfile while preserving the 'sort by date modified'.

```
$folder = glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\central/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
array_multisort(
array_map( 'filemtime', $folder ),
SORT_NUMERIC,
SORT_DESC,
$folder
);
```

Tried this:

```
    foreach($folder as $name){

           $root = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\central/'.$getname;
            echo 'This is wrong, I dont know what to put next';
    }
```

I'm more of a Pull Stack(pull from the web, stack in the file) right now so I'm still learning.

Comment: You don't need fopen/fclose with file_get_contents.

Comment: `$root = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\central/'.$getname;` makes little sense - `$getname` still contains the _full_ file content, you did not even split it into single lines anywhere yet ... Go check out https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not clear with my objective but here's the solution.

```
$getname = file(foldername.txt); // contains the folder names
$implodegetname = implode(",",$getname); //array to string
    
$folder = glob('C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite\central/*{{$implodegetname}}', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
array_multisort(
array_map( 'filemtime', $folder ),
SORT_NUMERIC,
SORT_DESC,
$folder
);
```